# package remove and delete from vendor folder

Tags: php, laravel

i install package via composer and now i would like to remove

i do

```
composer remove bjuppa/laravel-blog
```

then my blog page and my controller confused, so I go to vendor directory there is *bjuppa* folder, then I delete the folder from the *vendor*.

now i have this *

> "c/BlogServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory"

- error.

in laravel 6: service providers automatically attached. i don't know where it locates. i try config/app

any help please

Comment: after you remove from composer you must run `composer dump-autoload`. If problem still persists delete vendor folder and run `composer install`

Comment: when i run composer install....reinstall the removed package again

Comment: remove `bjuppa/laravel-blog` from your composer.json file, delete the vendor folder and run `composer install`

Comment: i do both step, but Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing bjuppa/metatagbag (v1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bjuppa/laravel-blog (v1.7.2): Loading from cache

Comment: should i also remove from **composer.lock**??

Comment: composer.lock no need to delete, it seems like you haven''t clear the bjuppa packages from composer.json file, search and delete any bjuppa package from your composer.json file and run install and dump-autoload.

Comment: after i run  _php artisan cache:clear_

**In ClassLoader.php line 444:** `include(C:\laragon\www\Getrest\vendor\composer/../bjuppa/laravel-blog/src/BlogServiceProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such fil
  e or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Normally `composer remove` used like this is enough:

```
composer remove bjuppa/laravel-blog
```

but if composer package is removed and config cache is not cleaned you cannot clean it, when you try like so

```
php artisan config:clear
```

you can get an error In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

> Class 'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider' not found

this is a dead end, unless you go deleting files

```
$rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

and run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It happens usually on automated deployment, when you copy files of a new release on top of old cache. Even if you cleared cache before copying. You end up with old cache and a new composer.json.

Comment: @mohammed i dont find `bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: Ok..because you clear the config..so removed your package at the end? @ShowMore

Comment: inside my laravel folder below app directory, there is bootstrap inside ->cache->only `packages.php` there is no config.php then  when i run `composer dump-autoload` same error -ProviderRepository.php line 208:-

Comment: You Can Search error class Full Path In Your Entire Project And Delete It. For example if your error said Class Flash Provider not found search for: ```Class 'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider' not found``` as full path in your project